# How to remove ordinals from datetime strings in google docs or excel?

Tags: excel, datetime, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a list of datetimes that happen to have the ordinal in them (1st, 2nd, 3rd).  This causes problems for working with dates and converting to unix time.

How to remove the 'rd' or 'th' suffixes from dates?

example dates:

```
April 23rd
Apr 24th
Apr 30th
May 1st
May 7th
May 8th
May 15th
May 21st
May 22nd
May 28th
Jun 18th
Jun 19th
Jun 26th
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an easier way but, you could use multiple IF and RIGHT statements. i.e. =IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="rd",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),[add next IF statement here])

Comment: Are you stating that the dates have no year? The last two characters are always the alphabetic ordinals or if there is no ordinal the last character will be an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"st",""),"nd",""),"rd",""),"th","")
```

and, to convert it to a "real" date with today's year:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"st",""),"nd",""),"rd",""),"th","")
```

or, shorter (and works in Excel, not sure about Google):

```
=LOOKUP(1E+307,--SUBSTITUTE(A1,{"st","nd","rd","th"},""))
```

Be sure to format it as a Date

Comment: The last one with the LOOKUP is really neat

Comment: Thanks.  It works in Excel; doesn't seem to work as is in Google Sheets

Comment: +1 to LOOKUP solution. Unfortunately Sheets doesn't like to ignore error values in binary lookups. The closest I could get (for now) using a similar strategy is `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--SUBSTITUTE(A1,{"st","nd","rd","th"},"")))`

Comment: @AdamL  Yes, that looks as if it should work.  I don't use Google Sheets, myself.

Answer (score 1):

If the dates were just text and always had the last two letters, then it would just be

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)
```

If you wanted to check that the letters were there first, you could use something like

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(A1,2)={"st","nd","rd","th"}),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),A1)
```

Has to be entered as an array formula in Google Sheets

```
=ArrayFormula(=IF(OR(RIGHT(A1,2)={"st","nd","rd","th"}),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),A1))
```